# Executing same action for multiple rules

Tags: ibm-datapower

I'm new with DP;

I got a MPGW's policy with *a lot* of rules and I wish them all, or at least the POST/PUT requests of them, to run a GWscript for logging purposes.
- Can I easily insert the GWS action to all the specified rules?
- Or can I make a single rule (executing the script) and have the actual specifically-intended rule to be processed next? 
(Is there multiple rules processing?)

TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As August already said you have the option of "Reusable Rules" using the Call Processing Rule but IMHO this becomes quite messy, especially if you have many rules.

I normally take one of two options which I call, "*Reusable Service*" or "*Switch Action*" (and, yes, I've made up those names myself so you won't find it in the DataPower documentation)...

The "Reusable Service" is something I have implemented for many customers and I normally use a XML Firewall in Loopback for it (but a MPGW will work too). You can have many different functions in there, e.g. logging, transformation, validation, etc. and then you have a "simpler" URL-Open() call to this service in each rule.
You can lock down the XMLFW to only listen to 127.0.0.1 and thus make it isolated. This will still force you to add the call to each and every Rule but maybe you can add the URL-Open() to an existing GWS or shared script...

The other approach which I have used for "REST" based gateways is to code a "Switch Action". You then set fewer rules (or maybe even just one) but I try to have one rule per HTTP Method and then in the first Action I add a GWS which (can log via "Reusable Service") looks at the URI (normally) and/or Header and run a Switch() to load a specific GWS module. Each GWS Module is named according to the Switch() so it is easy to keep track and the "Switch modules" can call other shared modules in turn making your code cleaner (and smaller).
The advantage of this is of course fewer rules and more efficient code but you loses some oversight (graphically) but as you have the modules separated matching your previous Rules you can get a grasp just by looking at the GWS files included. If you add one GWS directory per Service/Method/Rule you'll have an even easier task over viewing (or adding) code.

```
local:///GWS/MyMPGWRestGW/index.js  <-- This is your main script
local:///GWS/MyMPGWRestGW/POST/createSomething.js
local:///GWS/MyMPGWRestGW/POST/createSomethingElse.js
local:///GWS/MyMPGWRestGW/PUT/updateSomething.js
local:///GWS/MyMPGWRestGW/GET/fetchMeSomething.js
local:///GWS/MyMPGWRestGW/DELETE/deleteSomething.js
local:///GWS/MyMPGWRestGW/HEAD/echoSomething.js
```

In a DataPower firmware released sometime soon I hope (there is an open demo already) we will get a new service called "*API Gateway*" which might be usable in these kinds of scenarios. I don't have much information that I can share but if you grab the demo (a Docker setup) you can access the DataPower running it and see the new API Gateway service in action: https://github.com/ibm-apiconnect/apigateway-experimental

With that in mind there might be better tools for us soon to create these kinds of scenarios... NB! Note the **MIGHT** as we can't know what will actually be released or if we can use it as a Service or if it will be dedicated for API Connect only!

Comment: Let API Connect save us all.
My superior told me the client for whom this script is for, has a routing domain with less rules so we could apply the rule-by-rule approach, as primitive as it is not interesting. I am so fresh on DP I haven't acquainted yet with XML FW, so I was a somewhat-whelmed by your elaborated suggestion. I'll give you the benefit of "not sure I'd even get to try your method" acceptance of answer, in view that it might drive me to get to know the machine a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a call-processing-rule action you may want to check if fits your needs (if those are more complex than just one simple GatewayScript action). See KC on reusable rules at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS9H2Y_7.6.0/com.ibm.dp.doc/action_definingreusablerules.html
So either you add the Call Processing Rule action to all existing rules or you just drop the GatewayScript Action itself to all existing rules. It is "easy" but is some work to go.
Is it really needed to log all by default? This can easily flood your log system, so plan it well.
Also, how about the Log Action, could that fit your needs as well?
Sorry if my reply a bit chaotic but just typing what comes to my mind.

Comment: Sorry, took me a while to get back on this issue. I assumed I could go over each rule and stick in the GWscript, however I have wished I had a less redundant action. I appreciate your typing what comes to mind :)